# Floom Mootools Slider Not Supporting Images as Hyperlinks?

Tags: php, mootools

i have used floom mootools slider for my website. It is displaying images dynamically, but the hyperlinks assigned to the images are not working !

The javascript code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{$smarty.const.WEB_PATH}js/floom.js"></script> {literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready', function(e) {   
            var slides = $$('#blinds img');

}
            $('blinds').floom(slides, {
                slidesBase: '',

                sliceFxIn: {
                    top: 00
                }


            });
        });
</script>
```

My PHP Code, written inside a .tpl file to Display 5 Random Images is :

```
<div class="sideshow" style="overflow: hidden;">
{php}
    // integer starts at 0 before counting
    $i = 0; 
    $dir = './wallpapers/';
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file)) 
                $totalfiles++;
        }
    }
    // prints out how many were in the directory
    #echo "There were $totalfiles files";



$subcount=0;
foreach(glob('./wallpapers/*.*') as $filename)
{




        $readonlyfile = substr($filename, 13);
        #echo $readonlyfile;
        #echo "<br>";
        $lastchars=substr($readonlyfile, -12);
        $checkstring="-730x251.jpg";
            if($lastchars==$checkstring)
            {
            $subcount=$subcount+1;
            $filenameonly=substr($filename, 13);
            $finalfilealone=substr($filenameonly, 0, -12);
            $imgarr[$subcount]=$finalfilealone;



            }



}



{/php}

{php}

echo "<div id='blinds'>";

for($j=0;$j<1;$j++)
    {
    $generaterandomseq=rand(1,$subcount);
    $gennum=intval($generaterandomseq);
    $cntarray[$j]=$gennum;
    $presentval=$cntarray[$j];
    $makeimglink="http://4kwallpapers.in/wallpapers/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-730x251.jpg";
    $makenavlink="http://4kwallpapers.in/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-wallpapers.html";
    echo "<a href='$makenavlink'><img src='$makeimglink' /></a>";
    echo "<a href=$makenavlink><img src=$makeimglink /></a>";

    }

    for($j=0;$j<1;$j++)
    {
    $generaterandomseq=rand(1,$subcount);
    $gennum=intval($generaterandomseq);
    $cntarray[$j]=$gennum;
    $presentval=$cntarray[$j];
    $makeimglink="http://4kwallpapers.in/wallpapers/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-730x251.jpg";
    $makenavlink="http://4kwallpapers.in/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-wallpapers.html";
    echo "<a href='$makenavlink'><img src='$makeimglink' /></a>";
    }

    for($j=0;$j<1;$j++)
    {
    $generaterandomseq=rand(1,$subcount);
    $gennum=intval($generaterandomseq);
    $cntarray[$j]=$gennum;
    $presentval=$cntarray[$j];
    $makeimglink="http://4kwallpapers.in/wallpapers/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-730x251.jpg";
    $makenavlink="http://4kwallpapers.in/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-wallpapers.html";
    echo "<a href='$makenavlink'><img src='$makeimglink' /></a>";
    }

    for($j=0;$j<1;$j++)
    {
    $generaterandomseq=rand(1,$subcount);
    $gennum=intval($generaterandomseq);
    $cntarray[$j]=$gennum;
    $presentval=$cntarray[$j];
    $makeimglink="http://4kwallpapers.in/wallpapers/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-730x251.jpg";
    $makenavlink="http://4kwallpapers.in/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-wallpapers.html";
    echo "<a href='$makenavlink'><img src='$makeimglink' /></a>";
    }

    for($j=0;$j<1;$j++)
    {
    $generaterandomseq=rand(1,$subcount);
    $gennum=intval($generaterandomseq);
    $cntarray[$j]=$gennum;
    $presentval=$cntarray[$j];
    $makeimglink="http://4kwallpapers.in/wallpapers/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-730x251.jpg";
    $makenavlink="http://4kwallpapers.in/".$imgarr[$presentval]."-wallpapers.html";
    echo "<a href='$makenavlink'><img src='$makeimglink' /></a>";
    }


echo "</div>";
{/php}




</div>
```

The above program, first trims the contents of the files (wallpapers), to the left and right to get the exact wallpaper name.

You can see a live demo on : http://www.4kwallpapers.in
The homepage displays a slideshow, which uses the above coding.
It displays the images properly. But, the links are not working. Please help me fix this issue. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Could you add rendered HTML in this example: __[http://jsfiddle.net/rLru9/](http://jsfiddle.net/rLru9/)__ please. And notice also the commented line which I think should be removed in the link I post here.